# How to check if a value is greater than one number and less than another number in Lua?

Tags: lua

I need to check if a number is greater than or equal to 100 and less than 200.

if 100 =< x < 200 then

What is the proper syntax in Lua?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
if x >= 100 and x < 200 then
    -- your code
end
```

Just remember that most programming languages (with Python being a notable exception) don't support **chained comparison operators** and you have to explicitly compare twice and combine the results of the comparisons with a **logical and**.

Also, you wrote `=<` for *"greater than or equal to"*. In almost all programming languages the *"greater/smaller than or equal to"* operator comes with the comparison character first, e.g.: `<=`, `>=`.

Comment: Or `if 100 <= x and x < 200 then`, to match the OP's numberline approach, which is what some programmers prefer/recommend anyway.